# Azure - IPSec VPN Network Speed

Tags: azure, ipsec

We have a Microsoft DC R2 server running only an Interbase database application, all works fine and we can access this application via both Point to Site and Site to Site VPN.

Our transfer speeds for files is coming in at about 5Mbps which is fantastic.

When we access our software (locally) which pulls data from the server (Azure) we're seeing it clock speeds of about 125KBps.

This results in a 3-6 second wait before the dataset appears on screen within our application.

In a local environment this is done within 0.5 seconds.

I'm trying to get to the bottom of the issue as the Internet connection we are on is a 100Mbps feed.

I look at the Draytek router and assumed that this was the problem, however we have tested from multiple sites and ISPs and can't seem to get any improvement on application DB access speeds. SMB speeds remain impressive.

We're not too experienced in the Azure area but we can't work out any way of improving those speeds, if anybody has any suggestions that would be fantastic.

FYI We're using an A2 Windows deployment (approx 4Gb).

Regards,

Pottre11

Comment: Have you tried to do speed tests with another IPSec connection? Maybe some of your devices is a bottleneck when IPSec pass through is involved.

Comment: Hi vtortola, we've tried 3 different laptops/PCs and different locations and also tried site-to-site and point-to-site. SMB is where we expect but database traffic to and from the server never goes higher than 125Kbps and takes the time to present on screen.

Comment: The problem could be related with the latency not with the bandwith.
http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Network-latency-effects-on-application-performance